# "less than global reach"

Tags: adjectives, comparative-degree, qualifiers

> The current teleport sector consists of four primary types of service
>   providers, all with different strategies:
>
> •
>       In-house broadcasters - a limited number of broadcasters that have internal content distribution and management capabilities, which they
>   continue to use. Because these in-house operations serve only one
>   customer, and the customer's primary focus is producing rather than
>   distributing or managing the content, these operations have limited
>   capabilities. Dedicated in-house operations represent an expensive
>   solution that is not cost effective and not easily scalable.
>
> •
>       Telcos - telecommunications companies, some with business units focused on satellite services. Many of these companies are relatively
>   minor players on a global basis because they concentrate on a specific
>   region, and are tied to their own terrestrial network. Due to a lack
>   of focus on the satellite and broadcasting sectors, these companies
>   have had difficulty reacting to the dynamic needs of the industry,
>   although some have carved out specialized business units to focus on
>   satellite services.
>
> •
>       Satellite fleet operators (hybrids) - satellite carriers that had typically offered only transmission, but which have recently begun to
>   either acquire or partner with teleports and terrestrial fiber network
>   operators to create a global hybrid network. These carriers are
>   typically limited to their own satellite fleet, which means that they
>   are limited geographically, are not network neutral, focus on
>   providing transmission capacity and generally cannot offer content
>   management services, and are reticent to compete with their customers
>   who provide value-added services.
>
> •
>       Independents - traditional teleport operators founded by entrepreneurs to exploit the liberalization of satellite services in
>   major markets. Traditional teleport operators have continued to
>   innovate and prosper by reacting to the changing needs of customers,
>   but generally do not offer a comprehensive solution via hybrid
>   satellite-terrestrial fiber networks. Many of them are relatively
>   small, resulting in **less than global reach**, inability to scale to
>   meet customer needs, only limited savings for their customers, and a
>   lack of resources to invest in supporting emerging technologies.
>
> -- Prospectus: [RRSat Global Communications Network](http://www.nasdaq.com/markets/ipos/filing.ashx?filingid=4474585)

Can I use "less global reach", "narrower than global reach" or "shorter than global reach" instead?

Comment: It is not clear what dialect of English is being used.  This company is based in Israel.  The "Ltd." company names suggest British English, but the company's stock is listed on NASDAQ.  The use of "characterize" suggests American English.  The original poster is in China; I do not expect him to say which dialect of English is being used.

Comment: In American English, "teleport" is a science fiction term meaning "transmit a physical object a long distance at near-light, light, or (in fictional and/or ansible-enabled worlds) faster-than-light speeds.  "Teleport" is used in Star Trek, Niven's "Theory and Practice of Teleportation", and other science fiction works.  In American English, a "ground station" is the aerospace industry term for a terrestrial station that provides uplink, downlink, satellite monitoring, and/or satellite control transmission services.

Comment: Wow, what industry do you work in? I work for an aerospace campany in China. "Teleport" is almost synonymous with “ground application station", except for some techinical configurations. We have built lots of 'real teleports' for our clients across the world. @Japser

Comment: BTW, we call a terrestrial station that provides satellite monitoring, and/or satellite control transmission services a "ground control station". @Jasper

Comment: I don't think the "Ltd." company names suggest British English, just as saying "you have been shanghaied" doesn't suggest Chinglish. It was just one of the numerous overseas companies listed on NASDAQ.  @Jasper

Comment: The distinction between a "ground application station" and a "ground control station" seems useful.  Each is a kind of "ground station".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that example, the expression **less than global reach** means **not comprehensive coverage** or **incomplete coverage**, or **insufficient in extent of coverage**.

The three alternatives you propose are poor matches for that meaning.  A crucial issue is that the type of extent being discussed is idiomatically conceived of as a matter of *area*, hence my use of the word "coverage".  "Less global reach" implies a *perimeter*, which is close; "narrower" implies *width* and "shorter" implies *distance*, neither of which is the right physical metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

*Global reach* means your service can reach everywhere on earth. *Less than* that means you cannot reach everywhere on earth (less than everywhere).

So the usage **less than global reach** is appropriate to use in your example. Your suggestions don't work because:
*narrower* deals with width (not appropriate on a globe)
*shorter* deals with height (again not appropriate on a globe)

For *less global reach*, **than** is needed because you are making a comparison between global reach and the reach of the mentioned service providers.

Comment: Which does "less than" modify, "global" or "global reach"?

Comment: The primary noun is "reach". "global" modifies the extent of the "reach". So "less than" modifies "global" as it means "less than" the entire "globe".